# NMinimize in NMinimize ...why doesn't work?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to use NMinimize in NMinimize.

What I want to do is
1) Make and Input the candidate of numbers to func by 1 st NMinimize.
2) replace numbers with the candidate.
3) evaluate and seek the "t" which makes minimize the Plus@@.... by 2nd(Inner) NMinimize.
4) return the value( with t,which make the expression minimized)
[image]

I've modified my code

```
nums = Array[numbers, 10];
func[numbers_] := 
  Block[{}, 
   First@NMinimize[
     Plus @@ numbers[[1 ;; 4]] + (1 - t)*(Plus @@ 
         numbers[[5 ;; All]]), {t}]];
NMinimize[func[nums], nums]
```

but this returns

> NMinimize::nnum:
>   numbers[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3v8j.jpg)+numbers[2]+numbers[3]+numbers[4]+1.82905
>   (numbers[5]+numbers[6]+numbers[7]+numbers[8]+numbers[9]+numbers[10]) is not numerical value at {t} = {-0.829053}

Comment: You are trying to numerically minimize a *symbolic* expression: what are the values for the $n_i$? Also I would advise to use `n[i]` instead of `Subscript[n,i]`. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I just modified my code as advice. but how to replace   the expression in NMinimize in the "Block" with a numerical value that 1st NMinimize will assign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about this in one `NMinimize` statement instead of two:

```
g[ numbers_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ]&), t_ ] /; (Length @ numbers == 10) := (
    Plus @@ numbers[[1 ;; 4]] + (1 - t)*Plus @@ numbers[[5 ;;]]
)

vars = Array[ n, {10} ];

NMinimize[ g[vars, t], vars~Join~{t}, Reals ]
```

[image: result]

As you can see, the problem does not lead to a meaningful solution.